# Isothermic Surface

Tags: differential-geometry, minimal-surfaces

What is an Isothermic Surface intuitively? There are a couple of definitions, but I really don't understand what it means if a surface is isothermic. What are ist properties, what is it used for?

Comment: It could help if you told us why you are interested in isothermal surfaces.

Comment: Are isothermal and isothermic surfaces the same? I want to learn about isothermic surfaces, because of its applications in discrete minimal surfaces. Essentially the Derivation of s-isothermic surfaces over Koebe polyhedra down to discrete minimal surfaces.

Comment: Well... the tags suggest that you mean something like [this](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Isothermal_surface).

Comment: Indeed, those seem to be two names for the same thing. It looks like you may find [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0003096.pdf) helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're still looking for the discrete Definition, it is essentially a map $f:Z^2 -> R^3$, s.t. the cross Ratio is -1, i.e. we have conformal squares, which are Möbius invariant.

Comment: Thanks very much, exactly what I was looking for!